# How do I clear an array of a structure in C, and then free that memory?

Tags: c, struct

Two questions:

1. How to quickly clear an array of a structure?
2. How to free memory allocated by the structure's member?

Code:

```
struct sComputerNames
{
    TCHAR *sName;   // Using a pointer here to minimize stack memory.   
};

TCHAR *sComputer  = (TCHAR *) calloc(2048+1, sizeof(TCHAR));
struct sComputerNames sCN[4096] = {0};


_tcscpy(sComputer,L"PC1");
sCN[0].sName = (TCHAR *) calloc(128,sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(sCN[0].sName,128,sComputer);


// What is a better way to clear out the structure array?
for (DWORD i=0;i<4096;i++)
{
    free(sCN[i].sName);
    sCN[i].sName=NULL;
}


// Assign a new value
_tcscpy(sComputer,L"PC2");
sCN[0].sName = (TCHAR *) calloc(128,sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(sCN[0].sName,128,sComputer);


free(sCN);sCN=NULL;     // Erroring here - how to free memory allocated by sCN's members?
free(sComputer);sComputer=NULL;
```

Thank you!

Comment: free(sCN);sCN=NULL; sCN is on stack memory. So you can't free it. You have to do loop as what you have done to free mem of member. If you want to reallocate after some time then better to reuse same buffer. Keep one flag that indicate buffer is "in use", "free" or "need to allocate".

Comment: I assume this is the correct way of allocating memory for a structure - using a pointer for the member instead of allocating memory for the member (i.e. 4096 * 128)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing the array is easy:

```
memset(sCN, 0, sizeof(sCN));
```

As for the rest, you have some confusion about trying to free sCN which you didn't malloc(), and trying to free lots of names when you only calloc()'d one of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. Now I just need to free the memory allocated by the sName members. Looks like I'll have to loop?

Comment: The only reason to loop, is it produces tighter code. It makes sense to loop through an array, no matter what the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to free from the structure head, but it's not a pointer, and if it
were, you would still want to free the sName pointer's memory first.

You would free sCN[idx].sName -- where idx would be assigned by a for loop. If you want to zero the structure -- was not clear from your question -- call memset using sCN[idx] as the
starting address, 0 as the set value, and sizeof(sCN[idx]) as the length of the structure.

You would also have to free the memory of sComputer.

Comment: You don't have to have a do loop to free, but if you have an array of structures and each structure has a pointer, freeing the pointer is easier done with a for or while, but free and a for loop are not dependent on each other.

Comment: Can you show an example of freeing the pointers with a for while?

Answer (score 0):

While some libs have heap_min, or by other names, that will reset the allocation pools used by m/calloc and free, you're doing it very right.

Bear in mind that allocation pools are most commonly implemented using linked lists of allocation information nodes. On your example there will be a truck load of sequential callocs, hence the order by which you free should be the same order by which you allocated. That means the free call will find the element to free in the beginning of the linked list, minimizing search time.

Comment: I didn't went through your code to evaluate other eventual incorrections